# Why am I getting SQLSTATE[42501] error when running php artisan migrate?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I just don't understand for the life of me how this error's happening upon running `php artisan migrate` after creating a new table.

I've searched the web and SO and tried every single suggestion out there (like `php artisan migrate:fresh`) but nothing seems to be working.

What can I do to rectify this problem as this is holding me up big time?

```
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 
'posts' already exists (SQL: create table `posts` (`id` bigint 
 unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `user_id` int 
 unsigned not null, `body` varchar(140) not null, `created_at` 
 timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set 
 utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('body', 140);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your migration? @mr test

Comment: It should drop tables with migrate:fresh, can you show the code of the migration  file ? So we can rectify what's the issue

Comment: @Manjunath migration posted

Comment: @mare96 migration posted

Comment: Can you update migration for posts? Because there is problem. @mrtest

Comment: @mare96 woops sorry!  posted it now

Comment: Try to change `bigIncrements` to `increments` and be sure to have only one table named posts. Also instead `on('user')` I think your table is `users`  @mrtest

Comment: @mare96 just tried that and made sure I only have one table named posts, still getting the same error :(

Comment: Try to run now `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194022/discussion-between-mr-test-and-mare96).

Comment: Try adding `Schema::dropIfExists('posts');` in up function before create schema.

Answer (score 0):

Please drop the tables before running the migrate command or try php artisan migrate:fresh command.